# selecting form elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

if you have this code:

```
<form name="thing">
   <label>Are you a student?</label>
      <input name="choice" type="radio" value = "yes" checked />yes
      <input name="choice" type="radio" value="no" />no
</form>
```

then you can select the radios like so:

```
document.thing.choice[i].value
```

And then I assumed that in this case:

```
<form name="thing">
   <label name ="yes_no">Are you a student?
      <input name="choice" type="radio" value = "yes" checked />yes
      <input name="choice" type="radio" value="no" />no
  </label>
</form>
```

then you could select the radio values like so:

```
document.thing.yes_no.choice[i].value
```

why does this work for form and not label? Is it because form is an object in the DOM and label is not?

Also, is the name attribute valid for form still? Or should one only use ID's...

Comment: You're accessing elements based on the premise that the name is attached to the global window object, which is generally not a very good idea. You can select the radio's with `document.querySelectorAll('[name="choice"]')`

Comment: You shouldn't use `document.thing.…` at all. Instead, do `document.getElementsByName("choice")`

Comment: thanks @Bergi. what's the reason for this?

Comment: It's a crappy quirks introduced by IE (and copied by other browser for compatibility reasons). Names of elements could too easily collide with proper properties of the DOM nodes.